# In Twisted Python - Make sure a protocol instance would be completely deallocated

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, twisted.words

I have a pretty intensive chat socket server written in Twisted Python, I start it using internet.TCPServer with a factory and that factory references to a protocol object that handles all communications with the client.

How should I make sure a protocol instance completely destroys itself once a client has disconnected?

I've got a function named connectionLost that is fired up once a client disconnects and I try stopping all activity right there but I suspect some reactor stuff (like twisted.words instances) keep running for obsolete protocol instances.

What would be the best approach to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to answer this question, but it needs some clarification.  There's no such thing as a "twisted.words instance", for one thing - `twisted.words` is a package, not a class.  What specific instance do you believe still exists?  What specific behavior are you seeing which leads you to believe that your protocol instances are being kept alive too long?  Do you see log messages, or network traffic, or modified state on other objects, or what?  Simply put, you can't force an object to be deallocated in Python, you need to just remove all references to it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do my best to desrcibe what I was experiencing back then but details might not be accurate as I don't use this socket service anymore.  
Each new TCP socket connection started an XMPPClientFactory (twisted.words.protocols.jabber.client.XMPPClientFactory) instance which managed a connection to a jabber server, I expected the protocol instance to be deallocated and have the referenced client object destroyed once a TCP client disconnects while in reality it seemed like they the client jabber objects were not destroyed.  
Please let me know if this better describes the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, for sorting out this issue I have set a `__del__` method in the protocol class and I am now logging protocol instances that have not been garbage collected within 1 minute from the time the client has disconnected.

If anybody has any better solution I'll still be glad to hear about it but so far I have already fixed a few potential memory leaks using this log.

Thanks!

Comment: A `__del__` method is a really bad idea.  This will prevent cycles from being collected.  See <http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage>.